# How to find maven dependencies of any given project?

Tags: java, maven, aether

I am trying to building a separate project which can find maven dependencies of any given project. I was referring Aether samples but i could not find a way to define another project to find dependencies.

As shown in the following figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXZmb.png), Project 1 has dependencies of project 2 and project 2 has dependencies of project 3. If i select project 1 on dependency finder it should show all the dependencies of project 1 which are project 2.

[image]

I was referring following Aether code piece but i could not figure out a way to set another project (by setting pom file or project directory)

```
    RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();

    RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession( system );

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:1.0.0.v20140518" );

    ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
    descriptorRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
    descriptorRequest.setRepositories( Booter.newRepositories( system, session ) );

    ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = system.readArtifactDescriptor( session, descriptorRequest );

    for ( Dependency dependency : descriptorResult.getDependencies() )
    {
        System.out.println( dependency );
    }
```

Comment: mvn dependency:tree usually works for me.

Comment: It tries to build the maven project by downloading dependencies which can be get failed. I just wanted to know the list of dependencies according to POM structure without building.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` does not build the project but simply attempts to download the POM files for all dependencies that do not already exist in the local repository.  If you download `project A` from somewhere, which in turn depends on `project B` and `project C` (both of which are in a remote repository), Maven can determine the full dependency tree for `project A` only after downloading the POMs for `project B` and `project C`.  This is the reason behind downloading the POMs.

Comment: are you working on maven multimodule project?

Comment: Yes it is a multimodule project which contains many parent poms

Comment: Did you ever find a way how to do this? I am trying to do the same for a microservice architecture. Btw what is that Booter class that you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do it programatically. You could simply invoke [dependency:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html):

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

I would also recommend you invoke it with `-Dverbose` in case you're really, really having a hard time figuring why a certain version of a dependency is being chosen over another one (which you may be expecting it to be using instead).

Or, alternatively, if you'd like to see the dependencies in a flat form, you could also use [dependency:list](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html)

```
mvn dependency:list
```

Comment: please correct the spelling mistake,
mvn depenency:list - wrong,
mvn dependency:list - right

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse with maven2 plugin, then when you open pom file, it displays a couple of views to see dependencies as per your requirement.

Comment: Actually i want to get these programmatically in order to do some filtration. I even tried by accessing values by parsing XML but it does have problems when versions are defined at parent poms.